# How to run an interactive python script with nohup

Tags: scripts, python, programming, nohup

My script requires entering username and password, how do i run it with `nohup` along with the ability to interact with it at the same time.

Comment: The interacting part depends a bit on how the scrcipt works. Is it possible to share it in some way?

Comment: How about getting the values with a GUI program like `zenity`? In `bash` I’d do `IFS='|' read user pw< <(zenity --password --username)`. Just noticed, there’s a library: [`python-zenity`](https://pypi.org/project/python-zenity/)

Comment: Isn't there any default linux utility to facilitate this issue? @dessert I agree with Zenity and such similar alternatives

Comment: @Sebastian Stark: for now its just entering login/passwd while starting the script, nothing more. Also it runs infinitely.

Comment: @amodi Not sure what makes a program a default linux utility for you, but `zenity` is quite common I’d say.

Comment: @dessert thanks! Also, will checkout the python-zenity library :)

Comment: Might also be of help: [Simplest method of asking user for password using graphical dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15724658/6164712)

Comment: at least it would be important to know if the script can read the password from stdin or not.

Comment: Zenity is very common, although in my experience it's been missing on Lubuntu. I had to make it a dependency for some of my programs.  Other Linux distros which go with very minimal Python install may not contain `tkinter` as well. So it can be a bit challenging to find the right method.